# Задать дополнительный фон Body

Tags: html, css

Есть типичная разметка фона body

```
body {
    font-family: "PTSansRegular", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.6;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/body-bgi.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Сейчас в честь праздника, нужно сверху наложить еще один фон, в шапку сайта. Как это реализовать не потеряв старый фон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Вариант:

```
background-image: url(../img/1-image.png),  url(../img/2-image.png);
```

2 Вариант:

```
body{
   background-image: url(../img/1-image.png);
}  
body:after{
   position:absolute:
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:0;
   height:0;
   content:" ";
   background-image:  url(../img/2-image.png);
}
```